# selling products in an iphone app using self developed credit clearing services

Tags: iphone, billing

I'd like to sell products through my application (insurance policies) and I don't want to use the in-app purchase mechanism as it would mean sharing 30% of the product price. Instead I would like to provide the user with a page to enter his/her credit card details and perform the credit clearing through my own self-developed secured services.

My question: is selling products which are not content or features, using my own purchasing system, prohibited by Apple or appstore policy?

Comment: This is tangential to the question, but a heads-up if you don’t already know: collecting credit cards, at least in the United States, will mean that you need to be PCI-compliant. Be prepared to be able to prove that.

Answer (score 8):

Obviously, I am not a lawyer, but I think you’ll be OK. Here’s my interpretation of the three relevant rules from [the developer guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) (emphasis mine):

> 11.1 Apps that unlock or enable *additional features or functionality* with *mechanisms other than the App Store* will be rejected.
>
> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services *in an app* will be rejected.
>
> 11.3 Apps *using IAP* to purchase *physical goods* or *goods and services used outside of the application* will be rejected.

The first rule prohibits you from unlocking anything inside of your app with something other than the App Store. This would prevent you from, say, making a game that downloads new levels from your server based on your membership to a website.

The second rule prohibits you from, say, making a game and enabling PayPal in it to unlock more levels. Apple wants you to use in-app purchase for that.

The third rule—and this is where it gets interesting—prohibits you from using in-app purchase in an application to buy “physical goods” or “goods and services used outside of the application.” Nowhere does it say, however, that you can’t use other purchasing systems.

With that third rule, I think what Apple is saying is this: anything that runs on the iPhone *must* be purchased through the App Store, and everything purchased in the App Store *must* run on iOS. For something like insurance, which isn’t new functionality *in the app*, I think you’ll be OK. This is absolutely worth an e-mail to Apple’s technical support staff, but if you look at Amazon’s app, you can purchase physical goods using Amazon’s checkout system.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from Apple's Guidelines - 11.3 Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected.

So, you should be fine. This is validated by apps that are already in the Apple app store, such as Groupon, Fandango, Chegg and others that charge users credit cards for physical goods or goods consumed outside of the app without passing the transaction through Apple.

It would be great feedback for everyone to hear whether you had any difficulties with Apple when publishing your app or not.

Answer (score 1):

11.10

Insurance applications must be free, in legal-compliance in the regions distributed, and cannot use IAP
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Also read: http://www.quora.com/How-do-eBay-and-Groupon-get-around-Apples-in-app-purchase-system-despite-being-native-apps

In general you can sell physical products via an app. You cannot however use the InAppPurchase mechanism for this, but are required to use your own payment mechanism.

Ruling on this seems somewhat unclear from the guidelines. Would be interestig to hear whether your app got accepted.

Answer (score 0):

We just recently submitted an app that featured in-app purchase of non-digital goods and everything went through without issue.  Take a look at the following to get more insight:

[Does Apple test purchase of physical goods during their app approval process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367278/does-apple-test-purchase-of-physical-goods-during-their-app-approval-process/23496930#23496930)